# Check for an empty form element

Tags: javascript, html

```
var items = ["fname","lname","msg"];
if(document.forms['form_c'].items[0].value.length == 0)
    alert(items[0] + " is left blank");
```

array having ids of form elements
line 2: //checking an element to be empty

Comment: You should also add a `required` tag to the `<input>`s you have within your form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think form objects in JavaScript have an `items` property. You might want:

```
if (!document.forms.form_c.elements[0].value)
    alert(...);
```

The `required` attribute mentioned in the comments is an HTML5 feature not available in all browsers.